# Why do my async functions get stuck in infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to setup some functions to continuously fetch and send data back and forth. However, after sending, there needs to be a brief rest period (which is why I have asyncio.sleep(10)). So, I want to be continuously fetching data in my loop during this waiting time. My problem is once task #1 starts sleeping and task #2 begins executing, it never reverts back to task #1 when it wakes up. It gets stuck in this fetching data loop endlessly.

I tried fixing this problem with a global boolean variable to indicate when the sender was on cooldown but that felt like a cheap solution. I wanted to find out if there was a way to achieve my goals using asyncio built-in functions.

Trying to repeat this process:  fetch some data continuously -> send some data -> go on cooldown and continue fetching data during this period

```
import asyncio

data = []

async def fetcher():
    while True:
        # Some code continuously fetching data
        print("STUCK IN FETCHER")

async def sender():
    # Some code which sends data
    await asyncio.sleep(10)

async def main():
    while True:
        t1 = asyncio.create_task(sender())
        t2 = asyncio.create_task(fetcher())
        await t1

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: If your code that does the fetching and sending can’t be awaited, asyncio is going to provide any real value here. You’d be better off using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`. If there’s an actual reason to use asyncio here, though, you can use `asyncio.to_thread`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not awaiting anything in your fetcher, hence it is essentially blocking and doesn't give other coroutines the Chance to do some work. You can add `await asyncio.sleep(0)` which should help. Apart from this, you should also await the sleep in `sender()` as otherwise, it will not actually sleep 10 seconds, but just create a coroutine that's not executed.

Comment: I need the loop to be continuously fetching data, so I'm not awaiting any other function at any point. If I had await asyncio.sleep(0) it still doesn't allow task #1 to complete. Is there a way to cancel task #2 from within itself?

Comment: if I do 
import asyncio

data = []

async def fetcher():
    while True:
        # Some code continuously fetching data
        #print("STUCK IN FETCHER")
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def sender():
    # Some code which sends data
    print("START")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("DONE")

async def main():
    while True:
        t1 = asyncio.create_task(sender())
        t2 = asyncio.create_task(fetcher())
        await t1

asyncio.run(main())
I see start and done being printed. Another question is why do you start fetcher infinite loop multiple times

Answer (score 0):

`fetcher` is blocking/sync function. If you want to run them concurrently, it needs to put `fetcher` into another executor.

```py
import asyncio

data = []

def fetcher():
    """Blocking fetcher."""
    while True:
        # Some code continuously fetching data
        print("STUCK IN FETCHER")

async def sender():
    """Async sender."""
    while True:
        # Some code which sends data
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    await asyncio.gather(
        # https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor
        loop.run_in_executor(None, fetcher),
        sender(),
    )

asyncio.run(main())
```

It still needs to synchronise fetcher and sender on accessing `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what [Simon Hawe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14078758/simon-hawe) said..

```py
import asyncio

data = []

async def fetcher(event):
    print("fetch = start")
    while not event.is_set():
        # Some code continuously fetching data
        await asyncio.sleep(0) # This hands control to other coroutine
    print("fetch = end")

async def sender(event):
    print ("send = start")
    # Some code which sends data
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("send = done")
    event.set()

async def main():
    event = asyncio.Event()
    for _ in range(2):
        event.clear()
        t1 = asyncio.create_task(sender(event))
        t2 = asyncio.create_task(fetcher(event))
        await asyncio.gather(t1,t2)
        print("-")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Console result:

```
send = start
fetch = start
send = done
fetch = end
-
send = start
fetch = start
send = done
fetch = end
-
```

async.Event() is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event). The use of an event comes with a caution: The use of this method is not thread-safe. The set state of the event is available to all tasks that consumes it. As stated:

> **Set the event.** All tasks waiting for event to be set will be immediately awakened.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).